# Psiblast with multiple sequence alignment fails

Tags: bash, blast

Error in psiblast using -in_msa option
Running this code:

```
module load BLAST+/2.11.0-foss-2020b

psiblast -in_msa $MSA -db $database -out $workdir/psiblast_results/$date/tbs_MSA.txt -evalue 0.0001 -qcov_hsp_perc 25 -max_hsps 1 -max_target_seqs 5000 -outfmt 6 -num_iterations 3 -comp_based_stats 1 -num_threads 5
```

I get the following error:

```
BLAST query error: CAlnReader::GetSeqEntry(): Seq_entry is not available until after Read()
```

It should be noted that the code works perfectly fine for single protein queries, with the query option.
Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering your -in_msa for duplicate IDs

You can use *seqkit:*

```
seqkit rmdup ali.fas > ali_nodups.fas
```